# VBA How To Set Form In Function

Tags: vba, com, userform, solidworks

I add Form1.vb in my project but ı couldn't show it. Form1.show or Form1.ShowDialog didn't worked beacuse it type is class.
Here is the error message;

> bc30109 'form1' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression

Solution must be some think like that.

```
Private Sub Form1Func()
    Dim f1 As Object
    f1 = Form1
    f1.ShowDialog
End Sub
Private Sub OnButtonClick(cmd As Commands_e)
    Select Case cmd
        Case Commands_e.Export_As_SheetMetal
            Form1Func()
        Case Commands_e.AboutUs
            Application.ShowMessageBox("AboutUS")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Show` has no "()"

Comment: Might I also direct you to a blog related to `.show` by Mat's Mug:  [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)

Comment: I am wondering if you don't have a function or something named show, or maybe it's a version issue... mine does not input the request for an argument (parenthesis).

Comment: What is the error you're getting on that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Form1Func()
    Dim f1 As New Form1
    f1.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about other actions in your program, I cannot pinpoint why you're being asked to provide an argument for show (possibly a named function, etc.), but this is a way to ensure a form is called as an object:

```
Dim obj As Object:  Set obj = VBA.UserForms.Add("userform1")
obj.Show vbModeless
```

Specific to your error, the above code directly generates the userform object through vba.

Comment: Do you just want to remove the `Select Case` block and leave the userform.show?

Comment: @mesyen inside of `Private Sub OnButtonClick`, remove all content and just leave `Form1.Show`, and if that still gives object issues, then use the code i have above `dim obj...` and ensure you have the correct form name in the `.add()`